# Add a number to the dataframes created

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add a number from a range to the df's created by the following loop. Can this be done in the same loop or do I have to write an additional loop?

For example, this loop creates 3 df's where I'd like add 1, 2 and 3 to their names: df_X1, df_Y2, df_Z3.

```
dfs2 = {}
for x in ['X','Y','Z']:
    dfs2['df_{}'.format(x)] = dfs['df_{}0'.format(x)].add(dfs['df_{}1'.format(x)]).add(dfs['df_{}2'.format(x)]).reset_index(level=3).unstack().sort_index(level='S')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(['X','Y','Z']):
    print (i, x)
0 X
1 Y
2 Z
```

And all together - add `1`, because `python` counts from `0`:

```
#testing empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
dfs2 = {}
for i, x in enumerate(['X','Y','Z']):
    print (i, x)
    dfs2['df_{}{}'.format(x, i + 1)] = df #df is testing dataframe

print (dfs2)
{'df_Y2': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 'df_X1': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 'df_Z3': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []}

print (dfs2['df_X1'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```